npm error Unexpected end of input npm error A complete log of this run can be found in


npm error Unexpected end of input
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-16T09_01_12_566Z-debug-0.log

how to solve this problem?
I tried to solve. Commands I used:
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
rd /s /q node_modules
del package-lock.json


you deleted the packages but didn't reinstall it? by the way did you check the log file stored at the path given?
